# Merge boxed elements

Tags: rust

Assuming that the following function exists:

```
fn merge(a1: A, a2: A) -> A { /* implemented */ }
```

Is there a way to write the function for the same operation using boxed types? That is:

```
fn boxed_merge(a1: Box<A>, a2: Box<A>) -> Box<A> { /* ??? */ }
```

Comment: What do you consider a merger between `a1` and `a2`?

Comment: I consider a merge as: `merge(a1: A, a2: A) -> A`. Edited my question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can re-use your `merge` function, by dereferencing the boxes inside the `boxed_merge` function. Note that this will not re-use the allocations but instead create a new one

```
fn boxed_merge(a1: Box<A>, a2: Box<A>) -> Box<A> {
    Box::new(merge(*a1, *a2))
}
```

Comment: Good idea with the reuse of the non-box function.

Answer (score 4):

I would advocate that a by-value `merge` should *not* be your base implementation. Instead, a mutating method provides more flexibility. You can then build on that for by-value and by-boxed-value methods:

```
struct A(u8);

impl A {
    fn merge_ref(&mut self, other: &A) {
        self.0 += other.0
    }
}

fn merge(mut a1: A, a2: A) -> A { 
    a1.merge_ref(&a2);
    a1
}

fn boxed_merge(mut a1: Box<A>, a2: Box<A>) -> Box<A> {
    a1.merge_ref(&a2);
    a1
}

fn main() {
    let a1 = A(1);
    let a2 = A(2);

    let a3 = merge(a1, a2);

    let boxed_a3 = Box::new(a3);
    let boxed_a4 = Box::new(A(4));

    let boxed_a7 = boxed_merge(boxed_a3, boxed_a4);

    println!("{}", boxed_a7.0);
}
```

Notably, this will be more efficient in the boxed case as you don't have to perform any additional allocations.

[As oli_obk - ker points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44018378/merge-boxed-elements/44025556?noredirect=1#comment75082155_44025556):

> This only applies for merges of `Copy` structures. If you had two sets that are merged, the elements of the set might not be copyable

That could be addressed by taking the thing to merge in by value in `merge_ref` and using the same trick to move out of the box in the `boxed_merge` method:

```
struct B(Vec<u8>);

impl B {
    fn merge_ref(&mut self, other: B) {
        self.0.extend(other.0)
    }
}

fn merge(mut b1: B, b2: B) -> B { 
    b1.merge_ref(b2);
    b1
}

fn boxed_merge(mut b1: Box<B>, b2: Box<B>) -> Box<B> {
    b1.merge_ref(*b2);
    b1
}

fn main() {
    let b1 = B(vec![1]);
    let b2 = B(vec![2]);

    let b3 = merge(b1, b2);

    let boxed_b3 = Box::new(b3);
    let boxed_b4 = Box::new(B(vec![4]));

    let boxed_b7 = boxed_merge(boxed_b3, boxed_b4);

    println!("{:?}", boxed_b7.0);
}
```

We still don't have any extra allocation here.

Comment: This only applies for merges of Copy structures. If you had two sets that are merged, the elements of the set might not be copyable (e.g. `Box<T>`).

Comment: @oli_obk-ker that's true, but if that were the case I'd change to `fn merge_ref(&mut self, other: A)` which has the same benefits of avoiding extraneous allocation.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the contents of boxed arguments by dereferencing them and combine them in a new `Box`. For example:

```
fn merge(a1: Box<usize>, a2: Box<usize>) -> Box<usize> {
    Box::new(*a1 + *a2)
}

fn main() {
    let a1 = Box::new(1);
    let a2 = Box::new(2);

    println!("{}", merge(a1, a2));
}
```